# Can't serialize an object with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following object and I am trying to serialize it to Json with Json.NET

```
[Serializable]
public class FlightSelection : IEquatable<FlightSelection>
{
    public static readonly DateTime InitialDate;

    public FlightSelection();

    public FlightWeekSelectionType FlightWeekSelectionType { get; set; }
    public bool IsValidProposalLineWeeksExists { get; }
    public int Play { get; set; }
    public List<ProposalLineWeek> ProposalLineWeeks { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCount { get; }
    public int Skip { get; set; }

    public void ApplyPattern();
    public bool Equals(FlightSelection other);
    public override bool Equals(object obj);
    public bool[] ToBoolArray();
    public override string ToString();
}
```

I try to serialize it with following code:

```
var jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
var fs = new FlightSelection();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fs, Formatting.None, jsSettings);
```

I get the following error: `The 'obj' argument is not a FlightSelection object.`

I can't really understand why.  The only place in the object where I see 'obj' is in the Equals method.  Why does the serializer care about a method.

Am I missing something simple?

EDIT: Stack trace as requested in comments:

> at CC.Fusion.Business.Model.FlightSelection.Equals(Object obj)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.IndexOf(T[] array, T value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 count)
>      at System.Array.IndexOf[T](T[] array, T value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 count)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.IndexOf(T item)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at APProxyServer.APProxy.GetProposal(Int32 proposalID) in c:\Code.Net\ClearChannel\Sandbox\APProxyServer\APProxy\APProxy.svc.cs:line 194
>      at SyncInvokeGetProposal(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: You tried with Ignore Attribute also?

Comment: What is public FlightSelection();?  I don't think that would compile?

Comment: @PocketDews : The way it is , the code doesn't compile. I copied & pasted the code on a editor, fixed (by adding dummy return values) and compiled.I did not have any crash. Obtained result is the following : `{"FlightWeekSelectionType":null,"IsValidProposalLineWeeksExists":false,"Play":0,
"ProposalLineWeeks":null,"SelectedCount":5,"Skip":0}` . Can we have all the implementation? The crash might be related to your implementation. PS : Did you try to override GetHashCode?

Comment: @PocketDews The object is in the DLL that I have no source for.  What you see is from the Object Viewer.

Comment: @SLaks Question edited to provide stack trace.

Comment: @MechanicalObject I can't change the implementation because the object lives in an DLL that I have no way of changing the code in.

Comment: @AngryHacker Could you try to decompile it ? If it is not obfuscated, it might help. Here is a link for [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Comment: @AngryHacker Ok I see. One last idea _(and by curiosity, I would try it I had the dll :) )_. Could try to create a class that inherits from FlightSelection and which has only an override GetHashcode(). Something like `public class AngryHackerFlightSelection : FlightSelection {public override int GetHashCode(){return this.GetHashCode();}}`.

Comment: @MechanicalObject I went and got the source, so real deal - not decompiled.  http://pastebin.com/WQkP45mr

Comment: @MechanicalObject I tried your suggestion of creating an inherited class with an override, but I ended up with the same error.

Answer (score 4):

I looked @ the code you indicated (pastebin.com/WQkP45mr) if you change the implementation of Equals method coming from IEquitable contract in the following way, it works

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {

        //if (obj == null) return base.Equals(obj);

        //if (!(obj is FlightSelection))
        //    throw new InvalidCastException("The 'obj' argument is not a FlightSelection object.");
        //else
        //    return Equals(obj as FlightSelection);    

        var flightSelection = obj as FlightSelection;
        if (flightSelection == null)
            return false;
        return Equals(flightSelection);
    }
```

The result I obtained :

```
{"FlightWeekSelectionType":0,"Play":1,"ProposalLineWeeks":[],"SelectedCount":0,"
Skip":1,"IsValidProposalLineWeeksExists":false}
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I hope this helps...

**EDIT :**

If you can't modify source code the following works ok , I tested too.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            var fs = new AngryHackerFlightSelection();
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fs, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, jsSettings);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }

    public class AngryHackerFlightSelection : FlightSelection
    {
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var flightSelection = obj as FlightSelection;
            if (flightSelection == null)
                return false;
            return Equals(flightSelection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but this code is from another library that I can't change the code of.  As far as other suggestion to create a descendant class that overwrites Equals method...I can't do that either because `FlightSelection` is not the actual class I am serializing.  In reality, I am serializing a class called Proposal, which has a property List<ProposalLine> and class ProposalLine has a reference to the FlightSelection object.  So essentially, I'd have to create a set of proxy objects and copy everything into it.